# Ui component validation remove using js magento2

Tags: magento2, javascript, uicomponent, validation

I have a fieldset in my UI component. Depending on certain conditions, I show/hide fields within it. All fields are initially marked as required in the UI component. However, I want to remove the 'required' validation when the fields are hidden.

```
if (response.success == true) {
        $('[name="customer_image"]').closest('.admin__field').hide();
        $('[name="kyc_type"]').closest('.admin__field').hide();
        $('[name="kyc_proof"]').closest('.admin__field').hide();
        $('[name="proof_number"]').closest('.admin__field').hide();
}
```

My ui component fields is like

```
<fieldset name="proofdetails" sortOrder="20">
     <settings>
        <collapsible>true</collapsible>
        <opened>true</opened>
        <visible>true</visible>
        <label translate="true">Proof Details</label>
        <componentType>fieldset</componentType>
        <additionalClasses>
            <class name="purchase-form-proof-details">true</class>
        </additionalClasses>
    </settings>    
    <field name="customer_image">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Photo</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="string">jpg jpeg png</item>
                <item name="maxFileSize" xsi:type="number">8388608</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">imageUploader</item>
                <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customer_image</item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="goldscheme/purchase/uploadfile">
                    <param name="target_element_id">customer_image</param>
                    <param name="type">image</param>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
    <field name="kyc_type">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Ceymox\GoldScheme\Model\Config\Source\ProofType</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Proof Type</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">kyc_type</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">kyc_type</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
    <field name="kyc_proof">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Proof</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="string">jpg jpeg gif png pdf</item>
                <item name="maxFileSize" xsi:type="number">16777216</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">kyc_proof</item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="goldscheme/purchase/uploadfile"/>
            </item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
    <field name="proof_number">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Proof Number</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">proof_number</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">proof_number</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                     <item name="alphanumeric" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                     <item name="min_text_length" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                     <item name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">12</item>
                     <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
    <field name="pancard">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Pan Card</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="string">jpg jpeg gif png pdf</item>
                <item name="maxFileSize" xsi:type="number">16777216</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">pancard</item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="goldscheme/purchase/uploadfile"/>
            </item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
    <field name="pancard_number">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Pan Number</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">pancard_number</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">70</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">pancard_number</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                     <item name="alphanumeric" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                     <item name="min_text_length" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                     <item name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">12</item>
                     <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

How i remove validation when the field is not visible

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you

Step 1: Create a Custom JavaScript Component
First, you'll need to create a custom JavaScript component that listens for changes in your conditions (e.g., response from an API) and updates the required validation rule of your fields accordingly.

Create a JavaScript file in your module's web directory. For example, `view/adminhtml/web/js/custom-validation.js.`

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiRegistry'
], function ($, registry) {
    'use strict';

    return function () {
        // Example function to toggle required validation
        function toggleRequiredValidation(fields, state) {
            fields.forEach(function (fieldName) {
                var fieldComponent = registry.get('index = ' + fieldName);
                if (fieldComponent) {
                    fieldComponent.validation['required-entry'] = state;
                    fieldComponent.required(state);
                    fieldComponent.validate();
                }
            });
        }

        // Example usage based on a condition
        // Replace 'response.success' with your actual condition
        if (response.success == true) {
            // Fields you want to toggle validation for
            var fieldsToToggle = [
                'customer_image',
                'kyc_type',
                'kyc_proof',
                'proof_number'
            ];

            // Hide fields and remove required validation
            toggleRequiredValidation(fieldsToToggle, false);
        }
    };
});
```

Step 2: Include Your JavaScript Component in Your UI Component
Modify your UI component's XML layout to include the custom JavaScript component. You can do this by adding a  node to your fieldset or form component.

For example, if you're customizing a form in the admin panel, you might have a layout file like **view/adminhtml/ui_component/your_form.xml**. You can add the script like so:

```
<form ...>
    ...
    <settings>
        ...
        <deps>
            <dep>Test_ApiData/js/custom-validation</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    ...
</form>
```

Or, if you need to directly include it in a specific template, you might need to adjust the template to load your JS component.

Comment: I got solution for my issue. My answer is posted here. Than you @RanaZain

Answer (score 0):

In my JavaScript file, I wrote a function to remove validation based on the below answer.

```
toggleRequiredValidation: function (fields, state) {
        fields.forEach(function (fieldName) {
            var fieldComponent = uiRegistry.get('index = ' + fieldName);
            console.log('fieldComponent: ' + fieldComponent);
            if (fieldComponent) {
                console.log('Field found: ' + fieldName);
                fieldComponent.validation['required-entry'] = state;
                fieldComponent.validate();
                fieldComponent.error(false);
            } else {
                console.log('Field not found: ' + fieldName);
            }
        });
    },
```